# Which positive integers can occur as the genus of a numerical semigroup minimally generated by 3 (or 2) elements?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, semigroups-and-monoids

Let $S$ be a [numerical semigroup](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_semigroup). Let $g(S)=|\mathbb N \setminus S |$, where $\mathbb N$ here denotes the set of non-negative integers. Let $e(S)$ be the embedding dimension of $S$, i.e. the cardinality of the minimal generating set of $S$ (see the link for embedding dimension). My question is: for which integers $k>1$, can we say that all but finitely many positive integers occur as $g(S)$ for some $S$ with $e(S)=k$? Like what can we say for at least $k=2$ or $k=3$?

Answer (score 4):

The semigroup generated by $2$ and $2g+1$ has genus $g$, so every positive integer is the genus of a semigroup with two generators.

Assuming $b < 2a$ and $a < 2b+1$, the semigroup $\langle 3, 3a+1, 3b+2 \rangle$ has three generators and genus $a+b$.

Comment: Ah right .. that's just Sylvester ... thanks.  . How about with $e(S)=3$ ?

Comment: Response regarding three generators added.